# if and ifnot binding not working as expected

Tags: knockout.js

`highestBid` is defined as `ko.observable()`

My HTML code is:

```
<span data-bind="if:highestBid() === '-Infinity'">
     <span data-bind="text:price"></span> <small style="font-size:13px" class="text-muted ">Rs. (Initial Bid) </small>
</span>
<span data-bind="ifnot:highestBid() === '-Infinity'">
     <span data-bind="text:highestBid"></span> <small style="font-size:13px" class="text-muted ">Rs. (current Bid) </small>
</span>
```

Now the second ifnot condition is always executed even if `highestBid` is equal to `-Infinity`.
What I am doing wrong?

**Update:**
I have update my HTML as:

```
<span data-bind="text:highestBid()"></span>
<span data-bind="text:price"></span> 
<span data-bind="if:highestBid() === '-Infinity'">
      <span data-bind="text:price"></span> <small style="font-size:13px" class="text-muted ">Rs. (Initial Bid) </small>
 </span>
 <span data-bind="ifnot:highestBid() === '-Infinity'">
       <span data-bind="text:highestBid"></span> <small style="font-size:13px" class="text-muted ">Rs. (current Bid) </small>
 </span>
```

Just to see the values of `price` and `highestBid`. These values are working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `highestBid` can be either a `string` or `numeric` value, then dont compare using the `===` operator as it also evaluates the type of object. Use `==` operator instead in your data-bind condition.

Comment: `highestBid` is always a numeric value i.e may be infinity or some value (both are numeric's ) as he is comparing with string `==` best suits .on ligher side i came to know about infinity is js :D . thanks for bringing up `==` on the table . kudos mate +1

Answer (score 3):

It's completely fine with `if/ifnot` condition in the code but if there is any break in bindings i.e something is undefined if/ifnot inner code will show .

[**Sample Scenario here**](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26541/) to reproduce your issue

**view:**

```
<span data-bind="if:highestBid() === '-Infinity'">
     <span style="color:red;" data-bind="text:'ifCondtion'"></span> <small style="font-size:13px" class="text-muted ">Rs. (Initial Bid) </small>
</span>
<span data-bind="ifnot: highestBid() === '-Infinity'">
     <span style="color:red;" data-bind="text:'ifnotcondition'"></span> <small style="font-size:13px" class="text-muted ">Rs. (current Bid) </small>
</span>
```

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26540/)**

**Alternate Ways :**

You can use `negation` operator in view and avoid `ifnot` like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26543/)**

you can also avoid conditional checking in view(which make view dirty) and do it viewModel like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26542/)** (Preferable IMHO)

**If `-Infinity` is numeric check this :**
I thought -Infinity is a string tough it seems to be a numeric value then you shouldn't be using `===` as your are comparing with string `-Infinity` try less safer check `==` **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26544/)**

Comment: there is no break in binding. `price` remains same. `highestBid` value can be either `-Infinity` or some numeric value.

Comment: check the last update which should work for sure . came to from dandy answer `-Infinity` is a value not a string.